# python - issues converting string to number (float or integer)

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert string to numbers. It can be float, integer, or empty string.

```
def num(s):
     if not s: return ""
     try:
          return int(s)
     except ValueError:
          return float(s)
     else: return 0

str1 = ""
str2 = "0.0"
str3 = "1.1"
str4 = "10"

print("str1 = "+str(num(str1)))
print("str2 = "+str(num(str2)))
print("str3 = "+str(num(str3)))
print("str4 = "+str(num(str4)))
```

so, the output:

```
str1 =     <== OK
str2 = 0.0 <== I need this as integer 0
str3 = 1.1 <== OK
str4 = 10  <== OK
```

anyone can help?

Comment: Why do you want the string representation of a float to become an integer?!

Comment: I dont want string representation. I want 0 as integer.

Comment: Yes, you are converting, that is clear. My question is: why should `'0.0'` be converted to `0`, not `0.0`, when it clearly represents the latter?

Comment: cause i'm sending this as json, and it is going as string

Comment: @user3175226 that still does not explain why you want to convert a `float` to an `int`, since JSON defines an `int` type and that clearly is not an `int`.

Comment: Then why not use the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) instead of rolling your own function?

Comment: And in general, you are presenting an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of telling us what you're actually trying to do, you're telling us about a problem with your solution to what you're trying to do. Those are subtly different concepts. If what you're actually trying to do is decode JSON, then you should use the [built-in tools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to do so.

Comment: Also, is it only `'0.0'` you want special-cased? What about e.g. `'1.0'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"0.0"
```

is not a valid integer string. If you want to round off zeroes into integers then do it after you convert to a float.

```
def num(s):
    if not s: return ""
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        f = float(s)
        if f%1.0 < 0.0005:
            return int(f)
        else:
            return f
    else: return 0
```

Comment: @user3175226 no, you're wrong, this outputs `0` for input of `'0.0'`.

Comment: Bear in mind that if the `try` block includes `return`, the `else` will never run.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Live Running example @ http://codepad.org/9xIbFxJ1

```
def num(s):

     if not s:
         return ""

     try:

        list_s = s.split(".")

        # If there is no fractional part or fractional part is 0 return int(s) else float(s)

        if ( len(list_s) == 1 ) or ( int(list_s[1]) == 0 ):
            return int(s) 
        else:
            return float(s)

     except: 
        return 0
```

Comment: Nope it works perfectly for me !! What was your input / which python version are you using ?

Comment: im on osx with python 2.7.5. same problem again. everything is 0

Comment: @rvraghav93 don't use `is` to compare equality; this only works because CPython interns small integers, an implementation detail you should **not** be relying on for functionality.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Okay ! Noted ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def num(s):
    if not s:
        return ""
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return float(s) or 0
    else:
        return 0
```

It works as expected:

```
num('')
=> ''
num('0.0')
=> 0
num('1.1')
=> 1.1
num('10')
=> 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this way. If the float and int of the number are the same then it's an int, else it's a float.

```
def make_number(n):
    try:
        n = float(n)
        if n == int(n):
            return int(n)
        return float(n)
    except ValueError:
        return 0
```

Edit: I thought int("1.2") would coerce to 1, I was wrong.

Comment: This will return a number or a string, which isn't terribly helpful, but more importantly claims `"NOT A NUMBER!"` for three of the OP's four examples.

Comment: I fixed the issues. Thought int coerced float-like-strings to the rounded down version like it does to real floats.

Answer (score -1):

float(s) can convert string to float directly; and int(float(s)) will convert float to integer. Here we just need a tiny number to check whether the float can be an integer.

```
def num(s):
    if s == '': 
        return ''
    else:
        if float(s) < int(float(s)) + 0.0000000000001:
            return int(float(s))
        else:
            return float(s)
```

Comment: This is just a less efficient version of Andrew Johnson's answer; you have a minimum of three function calls for any non-empty string, and five if it's "integer-y".